# OSStatus error 1718449215

Tags: iphone, core-audio, record

I have created an iPhone application to record our voice. When I try to record, I am getting error message in following statement.

```
recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:&err];
```

Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215 "Operation could not be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)"

If I tried to record in .caf file, it is working fine. If I tried with .m4a, I am getting this error message.

Please help me to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: The question is out of date, but since I came here through Google I'd share this reference : [osstatus.com](https://www.osstatus.com) allows you to look up the error codes

Comment: @Daneo It may be old, but it's not out of date.  I had the same error in 2017!

Comment: Same error occurring in my case too. @Daneo

Answer (score 76, accepted):

1718449215 is the decimal representation of the four character code for the `kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError` error.

In general you can use something like this to get more information from the errors you receive:

```
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain
                          code:my_error_code
                          userInfo:nil];
NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
```

Comment: .m4a is a file format, not a codec. The codec you are recording in is determined by AVFormatIDKey.

Answer (score 13):

In case this helps others: I just had the same error, and it was caused by trying to create/use audio files in the wrong format. I had preset the recording to create a .caf file, but instead, called the file xxx.wav.

Comment: I had this same error when I had `AVFormatIDKey` set to `kAudioFormatLinearPCM` (`wav` format) but had forgotten to change the file extension on the destination file from `.m4a` to `.wav`.

Comment: Hi what extension should I have for `kAudioFormatAMR`? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

OSStatus error codes are pain, they are often too general to help. Did you try to [decode the four-char error code](https://gist.github.com/633827)? Sometimes that helps (other times you just get garbage). Create and show us a minimal code example that exhibits the problem. In this case I bet that the four-char code is `fmt?`. Google for the numeric code and you should be wiser.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this issue when I converted file type to .mp3 while previously I was using .caf format for recording sound with AVAudioRecorder. I again converted file type to.caf format & it works. You may use following formats

AAC, PCM, IMA4, ULAW, ILBC

Comment: Thanks for the formats, which file extensions are allowed by iOS? for examploe, what is the file extension for an ULAW formatted file?

Answer (score 1):

"NSDictionary" if it is empty, the default is high quality, if you set, this value will be very low, you can try to cancel these parameters:

```
setting[AVFormatIDKey] = @(kAudioFormatAppleIMA4);
setting[AVSampleRateKey] = @(600.0);
setting[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = @(1);
setting[AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey] = @(8);
```

Comment: I've removed the comments in Chinese from your post. If they are crucial to your answer, please translate them into English and add them back. StackOverflow is for English only. Thanks!

Comment: oh i see..thanks for your clarification.  Dear, please forgive my English is not very good, but you can try this answer, I hope this answer will  help to you

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, forgive my carelessness, I will pay attention to it later，and I want to say you're right.Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem at all :)

Comment: A wonderful day，In China this time has been late at night，Have a good time. Bye. 

Answer (score 1):

My favourite tool for deciphering OSStatus codes is https://osstatus.com

OSStatus error 1718449215 is `kAudioConverterErr_FormatNotSupported`, which may mean:

- The format you're trying to export to is not supported (double check the file extension of your output file URL).
- There's an issue with the `recordSettings`. One thing to look out for is that the value of the `AVFormatIDKey` matches the file extension of the output file URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in c or cpp code you can do this.

```
char code[4];
*((SInt32*)&code[0]) = error;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UInt32 code = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
NSLog(@"%4.4s"(char *)&code);
```

Comment: Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of how your code works.