# can not not play AAC format video on iOS which is made on Android

Tags: android, ios, audio, avaudioplayer, android-mediarecorder

I created a recorded AAC format audio on Android with following codes:

```
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(outputPathString);
```

Then I try to play it on iOS with following codes but failed :

```
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];

_audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
_audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[_audioPlayer play];
```

The error shows: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1937337955 "The operation couldn’t be completed.

Comment: Have you tried to play that video in QuickTime or iTunes??

Comment: @svrushal: i can play the audio file in any mac audio player, including QuickTime.

Comment: Then check for the audioURL?? is that URL is right or not??

Comment: @svrushal: the url is correct. when I replaced with another audio file with the same name and directory, it can play. So I believe the root cause must be within the audio file.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104398/avaudioplayer-initwithcontentsofurl-returns-nil-for-aac-m4a-files)

Comment: please post a URL to the AAC file that is not working so we can check the structure of the actual recorded file.