# Cordova iOS - can't record a media even though the file is created

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

I am trying to record a sound file using [cordova-plugin-media](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media), but I am always getting this error:

> {message: "Failed to initialize AVAudioRecorder: (null)↵", code: 1}

I am first creating the file, like this

```
iOSCreateFile(fileName, callback) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, (fs) => {
        fs.root.getFile(fileName, {
            create: true, 
            exclusive: false
        }, (fileEntry) => {
            console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
            // here I am getting true, so the file is obviously created
            callback(fileEntry.nativeURL);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('error create file: ' + error);
        });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log('error loading file system: ' + error);
    });
},
```

The `fileEntry.nativeURL` I am sending back looks like this

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0EE019AA-EFBA-4FB9-97EC-1F16FFDDA36B/tmp/1496663387924.wav
```

then, when this calls back, I am doing the following

```
// that long file path string is passed here
let soundRecord = new Media(filePath, () => {
    // success
    // more code
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And once it tries to execute the new statement, it gives me the Failed to initialize AVAudioRecorder error...

What am I doing wrong please?

EDIT: I also tried not creating a file, but only passing a file name string to the new Media object, like "1240215251.wav", and it's supposed to create it for me, but I am still getting the same error.

UPDATE: I have tried to catch the error in the native code, but I don't understand it very well, when I am debugging I can only see where the error is generated, but nothing else, please check the below code, I have commented where needed

```
- (void)startRecordingAudio:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    NSString* callbackId = command.callbackId;

#pragma unused(callbackId)

    NSString* mediaId = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
    CDVAudioFile* audioFile = [self audioFileForResource:[command argumentAtIndex:1] withId:mediaId doValidation:YES forRecording:YES];
    __block NSString* jsString = nil;
    __block NSString* errorMsg = @"";

    if ((audioFile != nil) && (audioFile.resourceURL != nil)) {
        __weak CDVSound* weakSelf = self;
        void (^startRecording)(void) = ^{
            NSError* __autoreleasing error = nil;
            if (audioFile.recorder != nil) {
                [audioFile.recorder stop];
                audioFile.recorder = nil;
            }
            if ([weakSelf hasAudioSession]) {
                if (![weakSelf.avSession.category isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord]) {
                    [weakSelf.avSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
                }

                if (![weakSelf.avSession setActive:YES error:&error]) {
                    // other audio with higher priority that does not allow mixing could cause this to fail
                    errorMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to record audio: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]];
                    // jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@(\"%@\",%d,%d);", @"cordova.require('cordova-plugin-media.Media').onStatus", mediaId, MEDIA_ERROR, MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED];
                    jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(\"%@\",%d,%@);", @"cordova.require('cordova-plugin-media.Media').onStatus", mediaId, MEDIA_ERROR, [weakSelf createMediaErrorWithCode:MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED message:errorMsg]];
                    [weakSelf.commandDelegate evalJs:jsString];
                    return;
                }
            }
            NSDictionary *audioSettings = @{AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                                             AVSampleRateKey: @(44100),
                                             AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @(1),
                                             AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityMedium)
                                             };
            audioFile.recorder = [[CDVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:audioFile.resourceURL settings:audioSettings error:&error];
            // HERE ^
            // Just after this audioFile.recorder declaration, the error variable below gets a value -  NSError *   domain:
            // @"NSOSStatusErrorDomain" - code: 1718449215  0x0000000170247e90

            bool recordingSuccess = NO;
            if (error == nil) {
                audioFile.recorder.delegate = weakSelf;
                audioFile.recorder.mediaId = mediaId;
                audioFile.recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
                recordingSuccess = [audioFile.recorder record];
                if (recordingSuccess) {
                    NSLog(@"Started recording audio sample '%@'", audioFile.resourcePath);
                    jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(\"%@\",%d,%d);", @"cordova.require('cordova-plugin-media.Media').onStatus", mediaId, MEDIA_STATE, MEDIA_RUNNING];
                    [weakSelf.commandDelegate evalJs:jsString];
                }
            }

            if ((error != nil) || (recordingSuccess == NO)) {
                // It then enters in one of below cases
                if (error != nil) {
                    errorMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to initialize AVAudioRecorder: %@\n", [error localizedFailureReason]];
                } else {
                    errorMsg = @"Failed to start recording using AVAudioRecorder";
                }
                audioFile.recorder = nil;
                if (weakSelf.avSession) {
                    [weakSelf.avSession setActive:NO error:nil];
                }
                jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(\"%@\",%d,%@);", @"cordova.require('cordova-plugin-media.Media').onStatus", mediaId, MEDIA_ERROR, [weakSelf createMediaErrorWithCode:MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED message:errorMsg]];
                [weakSelf.commandDelegate evalJs:jsString];
            }
        };
        ...
        // More irrelevant code of the method
        ...
}
```

Comment: Which version of media plugin are you using? Cos a similar issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12542  is recently fixed in version - 3.0.1 of media plugin

Comment: @Gandhi I just updated the plugin last night, so it can't be that, I even added the neccessary permission explanation string

Comment: I removed the plugin and then installed it with explicit version - cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media@3.0.1 --variable MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="Required for sound messages" --save, and still the same happens

Comment: I checked installing this plugin and it installs the latest version 3.0.2 which contains the fix.. So what I said earlier may not be applicable

Comment: Why dont you try using file plugin and try storing the file in cordova.file.dataDirectory? check out this link cfor more info on file operations - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Comment: @Gandhi just tried again, created a file in cordova.file.dataDirectory using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL, then I got a fileEntry object, and I got it's url which was like "file://....", and got the same error

Comment: I have tested one of the quick samples of the plugin, using just a .wav name and it's working fine. This looks like some incompatibility with the audio format and your device. Can you tell the device model and iOS version? Also, the native code you shared isn't from the last version of the plugin

Comment: Also tested with `.nativeURL` and it didn't work, media plugin only seems to support cdvfile or the file name without path, so keep trying with just the name or use `.toInternalURL()` to get a cdvfile path. I have tested with `.toInternalURL()` and also works fine on my device. So it still points to some incompatibility with your device

Comment: @jcesarmobile Very weird, I tried last night with 3.0.1 version, and it wasn't working, but now I tried again with 3.0.1 and now it seems to be ok, let me just further test it, and you can give an answer in the meanwhile

Comment: Maybe it didn't install correctly and you were hitting the issue @Gandhi told you, so kudos to him.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Can i post the answer jcesar?

Comment: Yes, if @SartherisStormhammer confirm that it works fine with 3.0.1 I think you should answer it because the bug you mentioned was probably the problem he was facing

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks for the confirmation Jcesar. As always its great talking to you

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer Please confirm whether the issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could have probably happened because of the usage of cordova media plugin VERSION 3.0.0. This version had issues with recording "wav" files in iOS. An [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12542) was already raised in media plugin's official issue tracker and its fixed in VERSION 3.0.1

So upgrading to the latest version of the plugin should resolve this issue. In this particular, the plugin wouldn't have got installed properly in the first try. Hopefully it should resolve the issue on proper upgrade. Cheers

Comment: sorry for the late response, everything is working just fine now, it seems all was just because of the old version of the plugin

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer thanks for the confirmation. Glad it worked

Answer (score 2):

I think the plugin is unable to create a AVAudioRecorder because you are passing a nativeURL, I don't know if this is supported. Did you try one of the [quick-examples](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#quick-example-4)? Without manually creating the file beforehand via iOSCreateFile.

Comment: yes, I've tried it, and just tested it again, I only passed a file name, like "1242124.wav", and I am still getting Failed to initialize AVAudioRecorder

Comment: Ok so far so good (or bad). Have you tried running your app with XCode? Do you see a console output like this: "Started recording audio sample ..." there? Maybe obj-c throws some error which is only visible in the native console.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, yes, I even try to debug the native code of the plugin in XCode, but since I am no iOS Dev, I can understand little, I only see in which part of the plugin code the error is being generated, I can update my answer with the native code part if you can understand it

Comment: I already had a look hat the native implementation of the plugin and I still think it is a problem with the path or the file extension. Could you try to play an audio file via a http link? And add NSLog statements and/or set breakpoints in XCode.

Comment: I just tried to read the file system and get a FileEntry object, which had the path to the file in "cdvfile:..." format, and I am still getting the same error everywhere.
What do you mean to play an audio via http? How?

Comment: Very strange, cdvfile is listed as the supported src parameter. Like shown here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#ios-quirks It's not the same as recording one but just to rule out that theres something fundametally wrong..

Comment: Yes, I even tried with a FileWriter object, that returned the path to the file like this "cdvfile://localhost/temporary/recording.wav", and I am still getting that error

Comment: Ah you updated your post: "OSStatus error 1718449215" means: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259078/osstatus-error-1718449215, I think it may be that the encoding is wrong or no audio recording device is found. Do you run it in a simulator or on a real device?

Comment: it is on a device, and I have given the app permission to use the microphone